# jQuery: ошибка при срабатывании триггера

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатии на блок `div` должно появиться окно выбора файла. Но в консоли при клике следующая ошибка:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
  $("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
})
```

```css
#test {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 140px;
  height: 107px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <input type='file'>
</div>
```

Если `<input type='file'>` переместить за пределы `<div>`, например:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<input type='file'>
```

В этом случае ошибки нет. Но как быть, если мне нужно, чтобы `<input>`располагался внутри `<div>`?

Comment: Клик по диву вызывает событие клика на инпуте, которое всплывает до клика по диву, который вызывает... И т. д.

Comment: `$("input[type='file']").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обойдемся стандартными средствами HTML.

Замени `<div>` на `<label for="file-input-id">` где `file-input-id` - это id файлового инпута:

```
<input type="file" id="my-file-input" hidden>
<label for="my-file-input">Open file</label>
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример: https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/RKzLWE